# Connecting one node to multiple Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to connect the multiple nodes together for one sample. For example:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///LabSample.csv' AS row
CREATE (i:ID)
SET i += row 

MATCH (i:ID) 
CREATE (l:laboratory {name:"New York"})
MERGE (i)-[:MADE]->(l)
```

What this does is connects each ID to their own personal New York lab node, instead of all of them connecting to one singular node. To put it another way, I want to have it radiated out from one singular node, rather than connected to their own disjointed nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///LabSample.csv' AS row
CREATE (i:ID) SET i += row 
CREATE (l:laboratory {name:"New York"})
MERGE (i)-[:MADE]->(l)
```

Basically remove the `MATCH` since it would rebind `i` to all the nodes matching the new pattern.

Side note: node labels are usually written in PascalCase, so favor `Id` over `ID` and `Laboratory` over `laboratory`.